# Hide some Legend Items in Line Chart

Tags: google-sheets

I have my line chart showing all the data properly, including some annotated values which are meant to act as the label in the last data point for the lines. I wanted to do it this way so that I don't have to show literally every data label for every data point.

I have everything working correctly, but I noticed I am unable to remove the annotated legend item without removing the series. By removing the series, I lose the label. Below is my chart.

[image]

As you can see, the last data points are working as labels (1092 for example). The problem is you can also see each annotated item in the legend (the colored dashes with no text next to them). How can I only show the legend items for Gained (green), Lost (red), Net (gained - lost) (yellow), and Total (blue), without the other dashes? Is this doable?

I am also open to seeing if there is another way to have only the last data point have a data label in Google Sheets. I was just working off of [this tutorial](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/how-can-i-format-individual-data-points-in-google-sheets-charts/).

Below is a screenshot of some of my data rows in an accompanying sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as the annotation column is specified as 'Label' for the primary column you shouldn't be seeing the former in legend

[image]

Comment: This was exactly my issue! I was including the annotated columns within the actual series and not just as labels for other series items. Thanks so much for pointing that out!